# How to generate a 20 byte array of hex values for an X509Certificate2 serial number?

Tags: c#, arrays, hex, x509

I need to generate a serial number for a self signed X509Certificate. [Serial numbers must be a positive integer of 20 bytes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.1.2.2)

I have a method that generates a random byte array of a given length, but I am having trouble using it to generate a 20 byte array of hex values.

```
        public static byte[] GenerateRandomByteArray(int Length)
        {
            char[] availableCharacters = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

            var identifier = new char[Length];
            var randomData = new byte[Length];
            var key = new byte[Length];

            using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(randomData);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < identifier.Length; i++)
            {
                var pos = randomData[i] % availableCharacters.Length;
                identifier[i] = availableCharacters[pos];
                key[i] = Convert.ToByte(identifier[i]);
            }
            return key;
        }
```

Using this method I get serial numbers that are the `ToString()` representation of the byte's decimal value.

```
    [0]: 65 'A'
    [1]: 54 '6'
    [2]: 48 '0'
    [3]: 69 'E'
    [4]: 53 '5'
    [5]: 50 '2'
    [6]: 50 '2'
    [7]: 56 '8'
    [8]: 52 '4'
    [9]: 56 '8'
    [10]: 51 '3'
    [11]: 57 '9'
    [12]: 51 '3'
    [13]: 66 'B'
    [14]: 48 '0'
    [15]: 55 '7'
    [16]: 67 'C'
    [17]: 65 'A'
    [18]: 57 '9'
    [19]: 57 '9'
```

turns into `41 36 30 45 35 32 32 38 34 38 33 39 33 42 30 37 43 41 39 39`

How do generate a serial number is the ToString of the hex value?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: I don't fully understand what's going on here, I admit. But I solved my problem by using this method:         

public static byte[] GenerateRandomSerial()
        {
            var buffer = new byte[20];
            Random r = new Random();
            r.NextBytes(buffer);
            return buffer;
        }

Comment: By limiting my byte range to CHAR values of 0-9 and A-F I was not allowing my code to generate the full 255 possible byte values.

Comment: `byte` can't have decimal or hex or binary value. It can be *represented* as hex, e.g.
`string result = string.Join(" ", randomData.Select(b => $"{b:X2}"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `System.Random`. In comments, you used `Random` class to generate random portion of the serial number. The problem with `Random` class is that it is pseudo RNG and returns same random sequence for given seed.

As Dmitry Bychenko pointed out in comments, you misunderstood the requirement. You can use full 0-255 byte value space for every octet in serial number. Limited char table (`[0-9A-F]`) is only hex presentation of byte value. Thus, your solution is simplified to this:

```
public static byte[] GenerateRandomByteArray(int Length)
{
    var randomData = new byte[Length];
    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(randomData);
    }

    return randomData;
}
```

`RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is now obsolete and it is recommend to use [RandomNumberGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator) factory methods to create appropriate RNG instance.